# Combine keys and values from two arrays into groups

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to combine two arrays with their keys and values, and I have the following PHP code:

```
foreach ($_POST['id'] as $key => $value) {
    $id_array[] = $value;
    //$array1[] = $update_array;
}

$id_array = array_fill_keys($id_array, 'id');
// var_dump($array1);
// exit();

foreach ($_POST['hruleid'] as $rkey => $rvalue) {
    $rule_array[] = $rvalue;
}

$rule_array = array_fill_keys($rule_array, 'ruleid');
// $result = array();
// foreach ($id_array as $i => $val) {
//     $result[] = array($val, $rule_array[$i]);
// }

echo "<pre>";
print_r($id_array);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($rule_array);
exit();
```

and its out put is:

```
Array
(
    [12] => id
    [15] => id
    [13] => id
    [16] => id
)
Array
(
    [0] => ruleid
    [1] => ruleid
    [2] => ruleid
    [3] => ruleid
 )
```

I  want it like this:

```
 Array
 (
 [0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 12
        [ruleid] => 0
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 15
        [ruleid] => 1
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 13
        [ruleid] => 2
    )
[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 16
        [ruleid] => 3
    )
 )
```

I  tried it like in the commented code but it is displaying an error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try array_merge : http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Comment: i tried arraya_merge...it gives me array like Array
(
    [0] => id
    [1] => id
    [2] => id
    [3] => id
    [4] => ruleid
    [5] => ruleid
    [6] => ruleid
    [7] => ruleid
)

Comment: Try @bhavin thummar answer... I think is the best solution for this problem.

Comment: @DivyeshJesadiya check my answer given below

Comment: everyone's answer are acceptable but i can choose only one....thanks for the help. +1 for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `foreach` to merge as your expected result

**update 1**  : simplified version of your code

```
if(count($_POST['id'])==count($_POST['hruleid']))
 {

     foreach ($_POST['id'] as $key => $value)
     {

        $new_array[] = array('id'=>$value,'rule_id'=>$_POST['hruleid'][$key]);

     }


 }
```

**old update:**

```
<?php

$id_array = Array(12,15,13,16);
$rule_array = Array (0,1,2,3);

foreach($id_array as $key=>$row)
{
    $new_array[]= array('id'=>$row,'rule_id'=>$rule_array[$key]);
}

print_r($new_array);


?>
```

**note** : above code only work if both array have same key and same count of array

Answer (score 2):

hey please check this solution. This is the proper solution there are two array one is data and other is final data. final data is stored the value of data array. This logic is used in the webservices.

```
  <?php 


        $data = array();
        $final_data = array();

        extract($_POST);

        for ($i=0; $i <sizeof($id) ; $i++) { 

            $data['id'] = $id[$i]; 
            $data['ruleid'] = $hruleid[$i];
            $final_data[] = $data;
        }


        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($final_data);
        echo '</pre>';
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just Try this

```
 foreach ($_POST['id'] as $key => $value) {
        $id_array[] = $value;
    }
    foreach ($_POST['hruleid'] as $rkey => $rvalue) {
        $rule_array[] = $rvalue;
    }
    $final=[];
    foreach ($id_array as $key=>$id){
        $final[]=['id'=>$id,'ruleid'=>(isset($rule_array[$key]))?$rule_array[$key]:''];
    }
```

If you array is like

```
 $id_array=[11,21,13,14];
 $rule_array=[2,3,5,6];
```

The above code will return value like

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Change your php script with this one, no need of `array_fill()`

```
$id_array=[];
$rule_array=[];
foreach ($_POST['id'] as $key => $value) {
    $id_array[] = $value;//it will be $id_array=[11,21,13,14];
}
foreach ($_POST['hruleid'] as $rkey => $rvalue) {
    $rule_array[] = $rvalue;////it will be $rule_array=[2,3,5,6];
}

$arr=[];
for($i=0;$i<4;$i++)
{
    $temp=[];
    $temp['id']=$id_array[$i];
    $temp['ruleid']=$rule_array[$i];
    array_push($arr,$temp);
}
echo "<pre>";print_r($arr);
```

A working fiddle is here [php fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/lite?code=%3C?php%5Cn$id_array=[11,21,13,14];%5Cn$rule_array=[2,3,5,6];%5Cn%5Cn$arr=[];%5Cnfor($i=0;$i%3C4;$i%20%20)%5Cn%7B%5Cn%20$temp=[];%5Cn%20$temp['id']=$id_array[$i];%5Cn%20$temp['ruleid']=$rule_array[$i];%5Cn%20array_push($arr,$temp);%5Cn%7D%5Cnecho%20%22%3Cpre%3E%22;print_r($arr);%5Cn%5Cn?%3E)

Answer (score 0):

**Script**

```
akshay@db-3325:/tmp$ cat test.php
<?php

$arr1=array(
    12 => 'id',
    15 => 'id',
    13 => 'id',
    16 => 'id',
);
$arr2 =array(
    0 => 'ruleid',
    1 => 'ruleid',
    2 => 'ruleid',
    3 => 'ruleid',
 );

print_r( 
   array_map(
      function($a,$b){ return array('id'=>$a,'ruleid'=>$b); },
      array_keys($arr1), 
      array_keys($arr2)
   ) 
 );

?>
```

**Output**

```
akshay@db-3325:/tmp$ php test.php 
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 12
            [ruleid] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 15
            [ruleid] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 13
            [ruleid] => 2
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 16
            [ruleid] => 3
        )

)
```